# Como alterar a velocidade do scroll do listView?

Tags: android

O scroll default do listView é muito rápido, e como desative o "recycle" do meu listView porque estou pintando alguns itens, percebi que está ficando lento quando eu passo deslizo sobre a lista. Alguém sabe como deixar o "deslize" do scroll mais lento para quando eu deslizar dar tempo do getView ir pintando meus itens sem engasgar minha lista? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você está usando o padrão View Holder no adapter? Se não, o engasgo é por conta disso e não porque você está pintando as views.

Comment: Querer *deixar o "deslize" do scroll mais lento* é "contra-natura". O objectivo é sempre tornar a aplicação o mais fluída possível. Poste o seu adapter

Comment: O que eu queria era apenas deixar a sensação de deslize mais pesado, assim como configuramos o deslize do mouse, com esse deslize mais pesado daria para ir pintando meus tens do listView sem a sensação de engasgamento.

Comment: Como eu já disse, o engasgo acontece por conta da falta do padrão View Holder. O list view consegue ter um scroll bem fluido e sem engasgos mesmo se tiver imagens em cada item. Como o @ramaral disse, poste seu adapter e podemos te ajudar na implementação.